# NumberFormatException For input string for french language

Tags: java, android, numberformatexception

I'm facing the problem with `NumberFormatException`. For input string for the French language. When I choose English / Spanish everything works fine! But when I choose French immediately it crashes and shows `NFException`.

```
public void TemperatureCurrentLevel(DosageCalculatorInputDto dosagecalculatorinput, DosageCalculatorResponseDto dosageCalculatorResponseDto) {
    double temp = dosagecalculatorinput.getTemperatureNow();
    Log.e("temp value", ""+Double.parseDouble(String.format("%.2f", Math.pow(temp, 3))));
    double power3 = Double.parseDouble(String.format("%.2f", Math.pow(temp, 3)));
    double power2 = Double.parseDouble(String.format("%.2f", Math.pow(temp, 2)));
    Double result = (-0.0000005 * power3 + 0.00006 * power2 + 0.0117 * temp - 0.4116);
    Log.i("teja1", "temperature factor current " + Double.parseDouble(String.format("%.3f", result)));

    dosageCalculatorResponseDto.setTemparatureFactoreCurrent( result);
}
```

**Logcat:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.elitecrest.orenda/com.elitecrest.orenda.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "512000,00"
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2721)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2782)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1521)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6228)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
 Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "512000,00"
    at java.lang.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1306)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:547)
    at com.elitecrest.orenda.utils.FormulationClass.TemperatureCurrentLevel(FormulationClass.java:64)
```

I'm facing problem with `power3` value. Its value is **512000.0 for English / Spanish**, but **512000,00 for French**.

Comment: I don't recommend using string to do this kind of truncation: `BigDecimal` should be used instead, e.g.: `int places = 3; BigDecimal val = BigDecimal.valueOf(1/3d); BigDecimal out = val.round(new MathContext(val.precision() + places - val.scale(), RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)); double result = out.doubleValue();`

Answer (score 0):

Try with `replace()`:

```
 Double.parseDouble(String.format("%.2f", Math.pow(temp, 3)).replace(',', '.'))
```

Comment: if i have **n** number of places what i have to do..? I need to replace all the places? I don't think that's a good practice.